# Problem with pst-pdf or auto-pst-pdf in texlive 2021

Tags: ghostscript, auto-pst-pdf, ps2pdf, texlive-2021

When using pst-pdf with texlive 2021, I get the error described below.
The same example works fine with texlive 2020.

First the latex source file pst-pdf-test.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5.5,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)%
  \pscircle*{5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Then the sequence of commands as described in pst-pdf documentation:

```
pdflatex pst-pdf-test.tex
latex pst-pdf-test.tex
dvips -o pst-pdf-test-pics.ps pst-pdf-test.dvi
ps2pdf pst-pdf-test-pics.ps
```

The ps2pdf command fails with the following ghostscript error:

```
%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY

Error: /undefined in .setopacityalpha
Operand stack:
   0.0   0.0   142.264   1.0
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:729/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:153/200(L)--   --dict:97/300(L)--   --dict:40/200(L)--   --dict:123/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 100406
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Initially, the problem arised using auto-pst-pdf, then I isolated the above, hopefully minimal, example producing the error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: try if it works if you add `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` to the ps2pdf call.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks. Since I'm actually using auto-pst-pdf, the option should be added as follows: \usepackage[pspdf=-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY]{auto-pst-pdf}